# KeyDown doesn't continuously fire when pressed and hold

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, jquery-events

I have this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SHg8MXA2pe4QuhS7z9k1?p=preview),

This contains a `div`, on which I bind a `keydown` event. On pressing right or left arrow, the div should start moving.

This works,  in all browsers, but when the key is *pressed and hold*, the first keydown event is fired immediately (div once moves), and it waits for a time gap, and then it continues to move.

So this means the `keydown` event is once fired, then the browser waits to detect if there is a subsequent `keyUp` event as well, then after a short time (when there is no keyup), it continues to fires `keydown` events.

(*to see the problem, focus on window, press right arrow and hold, div should move once 5px, then wait, and then again continue to move*)

**Question**: Is there a way around, so I can just keep the key pressed, and div should immediately start moving, without waiting to detect subsequent keyup (once)?

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode)
    if (e.keyCode == 39)
      move(5, 'left', $('.mover'))
    else if (e.keyCode == 37)
      move(-5, 'left', $('.mover'))
  })

})

function move(offset, direction, target) {
  console.log($(target))
  $(target).css(direction, (parseInt($(target).css(direction)) + offset) + 'px')
}
```

```css
.mover {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mover'></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest something on a timeout, like this

http://codepen.io/kevrowe/pen/qEgGVO

```
$(function() {
  var direction,
      movingTimeout = -1;

  $(window).on('keydown', function(e) {    
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
      direction = 'right';
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      direction = 'left';
    }  

    startMoving(direction);
  });

  function stopMoving() {
    clearTimeout(movingTimeout);
    movingTimeout = -1;
  }

  function startMoving(direction) {
    if (movingTimeout === -1) {      
      loop(direction);
    }
  }

  function loop(direction) {
    move(direction === 'left' ? -5 : 5, $('.mover'));
    movingTimeout = setTimeout(loop, 10, direction);
  }

  function move(offset, $target) {
    $target.css('left', (parseInt($target.css('left')) + offset) + 'px')
  }

  $(window).on('keyup', function(e) {    
    stopMoving();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

When keydown event occurs on the key you want to track, then store this information in a mapping or a flag somewhere.

When keyup event occurs, then clear the flag for the given key.

Then, on a timer, you could poll the state of the key mapping, and move the object for whatever key direction is being pressed.

Possibly there is a better solution then polling, but I don't know of a way to test if a key is down other than polling.

On keyup, would also need to check if needed to interrupt moving the object.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to just continuously run the move function in a loop until keyup happens

```
if (e.keyCode == 39){
  var stop = setInterval(function(){ 
    move(5, 'left', $('.mover'))
  }, 25);

  window.on("keyup", function(){
    //stop the loop
    clearInterval(stop);
    //and remove the keyup listener
    window.off("keyup", arguments.callee);
  })
} else if //etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that might interest, here is another approach to handle bi-directional movement. Ex: `up` + `right` keys = "North East" direction :

```
const FPS       = 60;
const STEP      = 5; 
const UP_KEY    = 90; // Z
const DOWN_KEY  = 83; // S
const LEFT_KEY  = 81; // Q
const RIGHT_KEY = 68; // D

const pressedKeys = [];
let movingTimeout = null;

function handleKeyDown(e) {
  pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
  switch(e.keyCode) {
    case DOWN_KEY:
    case LEFT_KEY:
    case RIGHT_KEY:
    case UP_KEY:
      e.preventDefault();
      startMoving();
  }
}

function handleKeyUp(e) {
  pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = false;
  const shouldStop = !pressedKeys[UP_KEY]
    && !pressedKeys[DOWN_KEY]
    && !pressedKeys[LEFT_KEY]
    && !pressedKeys[RIGHT_KEY]
  ;
  if(shouldStop) {
    stopMoving();
  }
}

function startMoving() {
  if(!movingTimeout){
    loop();
  }
}

function stopMoving() {
  clearTimeout(movingTimeout);
  movingTimeout = null;
}

function loop() {
  const x = pressedKeys[RIGHT_KEY] ? STEP
          : pressedKeys[LEFT_KEY] ? -STEP : 0;
  const y = pressedKeys[DOWN_KEY] ? STEP
          : pressedKeys[UP_KEY] ? -STEP : 0;
  move(x, y);
  movingTimeout = setTimeout(loop, 1000 / FPS);
}

function move(x, y) {
  // Implement you own logic here for positioning / handling collisions
  // Ex: store.dispatch({ type: "MOVE_PLAYER", x, y });
  console.log(`Moving ${x} ${y} !`);
}


window.addEventListener('keydown', e => handleKeyDown(e));
window.addEventListener('keyup', e => handleKeyUp(e));
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

pure javascript

```
<input id="some" type="text">
```

```js
var input=document.getElementById("some");
input.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){

if (e.which == 40) {
var stop = setInterval(function(){ 

 console.log("ss:");

        }, 60);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
            //stop the loop
            clearInterval(stop);
            //and remove the keyup listener
            window.removeEventListener("keyup", arguments.callee);
          })


     }


})
```